# Exibir Imagem do Diretório

Tags: primefaces

Preciso exibir uma imagem na aplicação a qual fica em diretório externo a aplicação. Estou utilizando da seguinte forma, porem imagem não é exibida. Fica como se o caminho estivesse incorreto.

```
public StreamedContent getImagem() {
        DefaultStreamedContent defaultStreamedContent = null;
        try {
            String caminhoArquivoCompleto = getCaminhoArquivoCompleto();
            File file = new File(caminhoArquivoCompleto);
            ByteArrayInputStream imagemStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
            defaultStreamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(imagemStream, "image/png");
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getCause());
        }
        return defaultStreamedContent;
    }


<p:graphicImage value="#{arquivo.imagem}" width="50" height="50" cache="false" />
```

Comment: Você está usando Windows ? O que retorna no método `getCaminhoArquivoCompleto()` ?

Comment: Uso Win, Linux e Mac OS.
public String getCaminhoArquivoCompleto() {
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(caminho)) {
   return PropertiesUtil.getValor(ConstantesUtil.CHAVES.UPLOAD) + caminho + nome;
  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: Debuga aí e fala o valor exato que está neste método por favor. Tenho uma suspeita mas antes eu preciso ter esta informação

Comment: /User/MeuUsuario/Downloads/uploadsistema

É um Diretório externo a aplicação o qual utilizo um .properties para salvar quando faço o upload. Detalhe que esta mesma imagem esta sendo utilizada para geração de um Relatório PDF e nele imprimir normalmente, minha dificuldade esta em fazer exibir na tela.

Comment: Olha, tenho uma suspeita no seguinte: Você usando Windows ele não vai reconhecer esse diretório porque o windows usa um método diferente pra acessar pastas ("\\user\\").

Comment: Estou usando MAC para desenvolvimento. E já não consigo exibir nele. Este caminho ai é dinâmico, na verdade ele vem configurado de um arquivo properties. Sendo que o mesmo e utilizado pra fazer o upload de imagens e arquivos e Downloads que ambos funcionam normal. meu único problema esta com exibir a imagem.